# iOS 6 App Store submission

Tags: app-store, submission, ios6

How long after iOS 6 comes out that developers HAVE to submit using iOS6?
My concern is that migrating my app to iOS6 will take a long time, and I would rather push out a new build right now with the partial features I implemented.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat after iOS 4 can out, the minimum Deployment Target requirements for submission were raised to 3.0.  Reportedly these requirements are or will rise to iOS 4.3 after iOS 6 comes out.  So developers likely won't be required to submit apps using an iOS 6 minimum Deployment Target until after iOS 7 or 8 comes out (unless Apple changes their mind, which is always possible).